# Create custom categories for widgets in live customization

Tags: php, wordpress

I realized that my previous question was completely wrong, so now I have edited my question.

I have created about 10 widgets for the WordPress theme that I have designed so that the user can edit my theme as he likes.

The way to make my widget is as follows (here I have included only two instead of 10 widgets to keep the code short):

```
if ( !function_exists( 'template_widget' ) ) {

  function template_widget() {

    // widget 1

    $args = array(
      'id' => 'index_widget_one',
      'class' => 'index_widget',
      'name' => __( 'widget to adjust the text on the home page', 'text_domain' ),
      'description' => __( 'Please select the widget you want to display', 'text_domain' ),
      'before_title' => '<div class="widget-content"> <h2>',
      'after_title' => '</h2>  </div>',
      'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-index">',
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

    // widget 2

    $args = array(
      'id' => 'footerSite',
      'class' => 'footer',
      'name' => __( 'footer', 'text_domain' ),
      'description' => __( 'Please use text widgets in this section', 'text_domain' ),
      'before_title' => ' <div class="footerTitle"> <h4>',
      'after_title' => ' </h4>  </div>',
      'before_widget' => '<div class="footerWidget">',
      'after_widget' => ' </div>',
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

    // In the same way, I created 8 more widgets in the following, which I have not included to shorten the code

  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'template_widget' );

}
```

And by placing this code in the place where I want the user to edit it, I create a widget:

```
<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('index_widget_one')) : else : ?><?php endif; ?>

<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('footerSite')) : else : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Everything works well and the widgets of each section can be edited right in their place through the WordPress settings in the customization or widgets section.

But my problem is that when I go to the customization section to edit the widgets, all the widgets that I have created for my template are gathered in a tab called **widgets**.

This is not what I want. For example, I want the widgets of the home page to be in the category or tab named {**home widgets**} or widgets related to the writing page in the tab named {**post widgets**}; So that the user knows the widgets related to which part of the template he is editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the CSS block inside `mytheme_customize_css()` Also, `font-size` is updated to reflect.

It should be like this.

```php
function mytheme_customize_css()
{
    ?>
         <style type="text/css">
            h1 { color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_color', '#000000'); ?>; }
            .title-template h2 {
                color: #00ff10;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
         </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customize_css');
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no visibility on your theme. You have to check what the current theme is. In the current theme, you have to check which code is setting this.

Comment: Recommended reading on WordPress theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/